# Multivariate K-means clustering in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm not sure if there's existing terminology for this, but I'll try to explain my question below.

So I have an existing k-means clustering algo that uses `scikit-learn`, with about 50 dimensions, corresponding to different dates. The data points are price deviations for each of the dates. I get clusters fine. However, I would like to amend this so that for each data point, along each dimension, we look at 2 variables of interest - let's say price deviations AND absolute price. In terms of the data array I would like to pass into `scikit-learn`'s KMeans function, I would go from something like this:

```
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
...               [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
```

to something like this

```
X = np.array([[(1, 0.2), (2, 0.5)], [(1, 1.1), (4, 0.6)], [(1, 0.33), (0, 1.1)],
...               [(10, 0.1), (2, 0.4)], [(10, 0.22), (4, 1.7)], [(10, 0.3), (0, 1.2)]])
```

(obviously these are made up numbers, but I hope you see what I'm getting at)

The problem is I believe that the KMeans in the `scikit-learn` library doesn't take tuples like this - which is understandable, because the traditional L2-norm doesn't make sense in this scenario. I'm wondering if there's a way to do this using a Python library. I could do it manually, of course, but even there I wouldn't know what the best distance norm to use would be. Maybe just an average of the Euclidean distance from the centroid for both values? If so I'd obviously normalize all my variables to mean 0, variance 1.

Hope this made sense, and thanks for your help!

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly, you're originally trying to find clusters in a 2D space. Then in your second scenario, you would be finding clusters spanning 2 non-overlapping 2D spaces. Your clusters might not end up meaning anything. You can consider turning them into a single, long vector, using a weighted distance function, or maybe run two separate kmeans. Think about what you're doing and what you *want*, and what kmeans will actually output.

Comment: Originally, the clusters are in a 50-D space - but I agree with the rest of your analysis. I was thinking about simply doubling my dimension space so that the 2nd metric would be independent of the original metric it is temporally associated with; this might be equivalent to what I was thinking about when I was considering an average of the distance in the original question. As for two separate KMeans, that's not really what I'm going for

Comment: You can do it all once, with 100-D space, than you get clusters of (deviation, absolute) pairs. Each deviation cluster is 1-on-1 linked to absolute value cluster.

Alternative, you can do 2x 50-D space clusters, than each deviation cluster, can have a different absolute-value cluster.

You could also do a 2-stage approach - where you first create say 5 absolute value clusters, and within those 10 deviation clusters.